# Java Chat (Messaging) between eclipse and enterprise web application

Tags: java, websocket, xmpp, chat

Scenario:
I want to add messaging feature to an eclipse plugin and a web application. Clients are eclipse users, and web application users. Whenever a client posts a message to the server with a specific topic, the web application users browsing that topic should immediately be aware of the incoming message.

What are the current java technologies that handle this scenario? I am searching a clean API, solution.

PS. The system has already spring dependencies, the server is Tomcat 7

Comment: A Web Messaging solution supporting both Java clients and Web clients is Lightstreamer ( http://www.lightstreamer.com ). Check out if it can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XMPP via [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) on the Eclipse client and use an existing [web based chat client](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/), or browser friendly [XMPP client library](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) for your web interface.

Since you are posting to a topic, I would suggest using either the multi user chat or pubsub extensions of XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the Eclipse Communication Framework: http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/